# Change first option of select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two date inputs & one drop down with first option "All"..

My problem is when I select dates, if both dates are same, then the first option of select should become blank.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var first = jQuery('#category').find('option').first();
    jQuery('#date_to').on('change', function (e) {
    if($('#date_to').val == $('#date_from').val) {
        first.remove();
    })
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: `val` is a method so requires trailing brackets to call it: `val()`

Comment: .... in addition to what Rory said, you also need to move the `)` of the `if` statement to before the `{`, rather than after the `}`. In future, you should check the console of your browser, as that would have highlighted these syntax errors for you.

Comment: Surely it would be better to disable irrelevant option(s) rather than remove. When  the dates change, it's much simpler to re-enable option(s) than to reinsert them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to remove first option you are required to put on change on both date pickers because user can pick any date and every time a user picks a date condition is executed. Well that is up to your need also.

**Following is the working code.**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var first = jQuery('#category').find('option').first();

    $('#date_to').on('change', function (e) {
        remove();
    });

    $('#date_from').on('change', function (e) {
        remove();
    });

    function remove () {
        if($('#date_to').val() == $('#date_from').val()) {
            first.remove();
        };
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#date_to, #date_from').on('change', remove)` would be more compact.

Comment: Also, provision can be made for reinsertion of `first`, as follows, `function remove () {
 if($('#date_to').val() == $('#date_from').val()) {
  first.detach();
 } else {
  first.prependTo("#category");
 }
}`

Answer (score 4):

Change `val` to `val()` because it is a method. You also need to move the `)` of the `if` statement to the correct place;

```
if ($('#date_to').val() == $('#date_from').val()) {
    first.remove();
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind me adding the complete answer. Please revert it if you don't want that information included.

Comment: @SureshK do you want to remove the first option element or just want to make it empty??